# Assign 1 and 0 values to numpy array depending on whether values are in list

Tags: arrays, numpy

I am looking for a way to filter numpy arrays based on a list

```
input_array = [[0,4,6],[2,1,1],[6,6,9]]
list=[9,4]
...
output_array = [[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,1]]
```

I am currently flattening the array, and turning it to a list and back. Looks very unpythonic:

```
    list=[9,4]
    shape = input_array.shape
    input_array = input_array.flatten()
    output_array = np.array([int(i in list) for i in input_array])
    output_array = output_array.reshape(shape)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get the mask of matches. Now, `np.in1d` flattens the input to `1D` before processing. So, the output from it is to be reshaped back to `2D` and then converted to `int` for an output with `0s` and `1s`.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
np.in1d(input_array, list).reshape(input_array.shape).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: input_array
Out[40]: 
array([[0, 4, 6],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [6, 6, 9]])

In [41]: list=[9,4]

In [42]: np.in1d(input_array, list).reshape(input_array.shape).astype(int)
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```